# Add/Subtract/etc element by the next element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have an array with [25, -6, 14, 7, 100]. The expected output is

```
Sum:        = 140
Difference: = -90
Product:    = -147000
```

Basically, the next element is subtracted/added to the current element when looping. That sum and product is easy as I only need to do

```java
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(" => " + array[I]);
  sum += i;
  product *= i;
}
```

The problem is that when I do `difference -= i`, it gives me `-108`, which is wrong. And when there is only a single element in the array, it gives me the negative form of the element. e.g.

```java
String[] array = [32] // outputs -32
```

I tried looping through the code like:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumbers.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(arrayNumbers[i] - arrayNumbers[i + 1]);
}
```

and it gives me `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND THE ANSWER

```java
int[] array = {25, -6, 14, 7, 100}

int sum = 0;
int product = 1;
int difference = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(" => " + array[i]);
  sum += i;
  product *= I;
  if (i == 0)
    difference = i;
  else
    difference -= i;
}
```

Comment: welp, worth a try

Answer (score 0):

you are basing you calculation on index while you must base it on array[index]

```
var sum=0;
var difference=0;
var product=1;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(" => " + i);
  sum += array[i];
  if (i ==0)
    difference+=array[i];
  else 
    difference-=array[i];
  product *= array[i];
}
```

Comment: i didnt get why you underscored my answer . your answer wont give you that result :)

Comment: sorry it wasn't me. and thanks, this also worked

Comment: oh right, there's a bug when there are two consecutive negative numbers in the array, e.g. `{-4,-3}`  outputs `-1`.  should be `-7`

Answer (score -1):

This Exception
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1"
is due to the reason that whin i=arrayNumbers.length-1,then in the Code:

the arrayNumbers[i + 1] gives an exception as it is accessing the arrayNumbers[arrayNumbers.length];